# GroupBy arrays of strings by two Keys and sum a value

Tags: vb.net, linq, csv

I have CSV file with 3 columns: `ID`, `Date` and `value`.

```
204;2021-04-15;2,8
204;2021-04-15;2,8
103;2021-04-15;2,8
103;2021-04-15;2,8
103;2021-04-15;5,6
204;2021-04-14;2,8
200;2021-04-14;2,8
204;2021-04-14;2,8
204;2021-04-14;2,8
200;2021-04-14;2,8
103;2021-04-14;2,8
103;2021-04-14;2,8
204;2021-04-13;2,8
204;2021-04-13;5,6
200;2021-04-13;2,8
200;2021-04-13;2,8
204;2021-04-13;2,8
```

I need to Group strings by `ID` and `Date` and get the total sum of `Value` of grouped results.
Unfortunately, I don't understand how can I do this.
I use this code, but it doesn't give the expected results:

```
IO.File.WriteAllLines(outputFile1, IO.File.ReadLines(inputFile1).
    Select(Function(x) x.Split(";"c)).
    GroupBy(Function(x) {x(0), x(1)}).
    Select(Function(x)
               Return String.Format(
                "{0};{1};{2}",
                x.Select(Function(y) y(0)).First,
                x.Select(Function(y) y(1)).First,
                x.Sum(Function(y) Decimal.Parse(y(2))))
           End Function).ToArray)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem in the way you're creating the Keys used to group the string content.
This doesn't work in VB.Net:

```
GroupBy(Function(x) {x(0), x(1)})
```

You need a [Key specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/key):

> The Key keyword enables you to specify behavior for properties of
> anonymous types. Only properties you designate as key properties
> participate in tests of equality between anonymous type instances, or
> calculation of hash code values. The values of key properties cannot
> be changed.

which changes the code in:

```
GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key .idx = x(0), Key .date = x(1)})
```

Using Language version 15.3+, you can use `ValueTuples` as Keys selectors. E.g.,:

```
GroupBy(Function(x) (x(0), x(1)))
```

The overall query then becomes:

```
Dim lines = File.ReadLines(inputFile1).
    Select(Function(x) x.Split(";"c)).
    GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key .idx = x(0), Key .date = x(1)}).
    Select(Function(x) String.Format(
        "{0};{1};{2}", x.Key.idx, x.Key.date, x.Sum(Function(v) Decimal.Parse(v(2))))).
    ToArray()

IO.File.WriteAllLines(lines)
```

You can also build an intermediate anonymous object, which may be (possibly) simpler to evaluate while debugging, since you can inspect all the values as class properties:
<sub>Here, using an interpolated string</sub>

```
Dim lines = File.ReadLines(inputFile1).
    Select(Function(l) l.Split(";"c)).
    Select(Function(s) New With {.idx = s(0), .date = s(1), .value = Decimal.Parse(s(2))}).
    GroupBy(Function(a) New With {Key a.idx, Key a.date}).
    Select(Function(g) $"{g.Key.idx};{g.Key.date};{g.Sum(Function(v) v.value)}").ToArray()
```

As a note, your *decimal values* use a comma as the decimal separator, so consider that it may not parse correctly in different languages.
In that case, add an IFormatProvider that can handle the conversion, e.g.,:

```
Select(Function(s) New With {.idx = s(0), .date = s(1), 
    .value = Decimal.Parse(s(2), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"))})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With yours help I got it work!